# Axios sends a post to the duplicate url

Tags: reactjs, http, axios

What I'm trying to do is send a request to this local ip address but it keeps returning error 404. I went to look at the browser console and it is duplicating the url.

React + axios code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { getToken } from "./auth";

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: '10.0.0.10:3333'
  });

api.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
  const token = getToken();
  if (token) {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }
  return config;
});

export default api;
```

Component code

```
try {
        const response = await api.post("/sessions", { email, password });
        login(response.data.token);
        this.props.history.push("/app");
      } catch (err) {
        this.setState({
          error:
            "Error"
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Could you share the component who use this implementation?

Comment: Okay, I added the component

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it. Just add the `http://10.0.0.10`

```
And then install Axios
```

To install CORS:

```
npm i cors


const cors = require ('cors')
app.use (cors ()) (put at the beginning)
```

Comment: And it work? I don't understand how this solution is related to your issue.

Comment: It worked. But I also didn't understand why it is that way.

Answer (score 0):

Where you are instantiating your instance of axios (called `api`) with
`baseUrl: 10.0.0.10:3333` you are setting the base path that all your requests from this instance will go, or in otherwords it will prefix all of your requests with this.
So to get this duplication I'm assuming you are also writing the full url where you are calling api.post() like:

```
api.post('10.0.0.10:3333/sessions', (response) => {
    // handle response
})
```

All you need to write is:

```
api.post('/sessions', (response) => {
    // handle response
})
```

Comment: I'm not actually calling it the way you put it. I just added the component code.

Comment: What i'm realizing is that this first url is always the source of my request, but i still haven't been able to find what the problem is. I have also used my ide's search function and found nothing about this first url.

Answer (score 0):

how about add prefix "http://" before base url?

Comment: That's what I did